# How to resolve UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY with Vscode on Windows

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code, certificate

When opening a SQL script with VS Code on Windows I get the messages:

> Initializing SQL tools service for the mssql extension. Note: mssql
>   commands will be available after installing the service.
>
> Platform: win32, x86_64 (Windows)
>
> Installing SQL tools service to
>   c:\Users\BRITTG2.vscode\extensions\ms-mssql.mssql-1.8.0\sqltoolsservice\1.8.0\Windows.
>   Downloading
>   https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/7/8/e781cf8f-9c3f-4ad5-bd0c-f3c62b8bc6bd/microsoft.sqltools.servicelayer-win-x64-netcoreapp2.2.zip
>   [ERROR] Error: Request error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

How do I resolve this error?  Note I am behind a corp. fw

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/215

Comment: it would if I had a proxy I could configure.  I cannot see one configured on my machine.  Perhaps my corporate fw handles it all automagically.

Comment: Configuring an empty proxy as per the link to github issue doesn't change anything either.

Comment: Asking you orgs admins might help

Answer (score 5):

You can turn off `File -> Preferences -> Settings`, search for property `http.proxyStrictSSL` and turn it off.

Close visual studio and open again, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today when VSCode was running from WSL2 with Ubuntu 20-04 distro. Not your case exactly, but could be useful to others.

In my case the root cause is that our corporate network requires two custom CA certificates from ZScaler. You can easily verify whether your case is similar - google for the exact procedure, it is not complicated.

Anyway, I saved the certificates in a pem file and then followed the instructions on https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store to install them:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates
$ sudo cp local-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
```

After that I closed and reopened VS Code and the SQL tools service installed just fine.